# Flot: series is unexpected identifier in options

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Newbie question. With the flot jquery library I'm trying to set the series options, but I'm getting an error: "Unexpected identifier" on the `series: {` line.

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-options. Is there just something i'm not understanding?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flot Graph Testing</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        var options = {
            grid: {
                show: false
            }
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show:true
                }
            }
        };

        var rawdata = [[0, 3], [2, 8], [4, 5], [6, 13]];
        var data = [{data: rawdata }]
        $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);

        // Add the Flot version string to the footer

        $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Flot graph</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="placeholder" class="my-placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
        </div>
        <p>This is a flot graph</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma to separate the properties of the `options` object:

```
    var options = {
        grid: {
            show: false
        }, // <-- comma
        series: {
            bars: {
                show:true
            }
        }
    };
```